# iterate over multiple ranges of same array

Tags: c++, c, for-loop, iteration

I have an array containing items and an array containing ranges,

```
struct range
{
    uint32_t head;
    uint32_t tail;
};
```

`head` and `tail` are start and end indices, each `head` is 64-byte aligned.

```
         0     64    128   192   256   320   384   448   512 ...
  items: |--------|  |----------------|      |---------|     ...
 ranges: head  tail  head          tail      head   tail     ...
```

How can I iterate over items bounded by a range without double for loop like,

```
for (uint32_t i = 0; i < range_count; i++)
{
    for(uint32_t j = ranges[i].head; j < ranges[i].tail; j++)
    {
        ... items[j];
        ...
    }
}
```

just using single for loop?

Comment: What's the problem with using the double for loop?  It has the advantage of being easy to understand.

Comment: should the inner loop's condition be "`j < ranges[i].tail`"? As shown, it does not make much sense.

Comment: What is bad about the current solution?

Comment: you could write a custom iterator class to do this but the loops are much simpler

Comment: As ranges may overlap, use the double loop.

Comment: Can you give some more information about why you don't want a nested loop?

Comment: Please decide whether you want to have C++ or C code and remove the other tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I mean, I would suggest the double `for` loop solution over this, but sure, example:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

struct range
{
  std::uint32_t head;
  std::uint32_t tail;
};

int
main()
{
  range r[5]{ { 1, 4 }, { 5, 7 }, { 2, 5 }, { 8, 9 }, { 4, 7 } };

  for (std::size_t i = 0, j = 0, ranges = std::size(r); i < ranges;) {
    auto const index = r[i].head + j;
    std::cout << index << ' ';

    if (index == r[i].tail) {
      j = 0;
      ++i;
      std::cout << '\n';
    } else {
      ++j;
    }
  }
}
```

I don't suggest this. The solution you have in the answer is more readable.